# Compiling C source code for Windows using libcurl

Tags: c, windows, mingw, libcurl

Compiling C source code for Windows using libcurl using mingw32 and libcurl32. The command line below:

```
gcc -c -I "c:\curl\include" -L "c:\curl\lib" -o simple.exe simple.c
```

The compilation runs successfully, generating the exe file. But when I try to run it I get the message:

Unsupported 16-bit application. The program or feature "simple.exe" cannot start or run due to an incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows.

gcc (MinGW-W64 i686-ucrt-posix-dwarf, built by Brecht Sanders) 12.2.0

curl 7.83.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.83.1 Schannel Release-Date: 2022-05-13 Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s smtp smtps telnet tftp Features: AsynchDNS HSTS IPv6 Kerberos Largefile NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI UnixSockets

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide details about the GCC compiler you're using, such as where it's from and what version it is.

Comment: gcc (MinGW-W64 i686-ucrt-posix-dwarf, built by Brecht Sanders) 12.2.0

curl 7.83.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.83.1 Schannel
Release-Date: 2022-05-13
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS HSTS IPv6 Kerberos Largefile NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI UnixSockets

Answer (score 5):

> Unsupported 16-bit application. The program or feature "simple.exe" cannot start or run due to an incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows.

`gcc -c` compiles an object file, `-o simple.exe` usage is wrong, it should be `-o simple.obj` or `-o simple.o`. You get an object file named `simple.exe`, object files can't run.

Remove `-c` and add `-lcurl` to link the executable with libcurl:

```
gcc -I "c:\curl\include" -L "c:\curl\lib" -o simple.exe simple.c -lcurl
```

Comment: gcc -I "c:\curl\include" -L "c:\curl\lib" -o simple.exe simple.c -lcurl

c:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: internal error: aborting at ../../ld/ldlang.c:527 in compare_section
c:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: please report this bug
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: This error is off-topic here. *Please report this bug*. I suggest that you uninstall MinGW and use MSYS2 with a better GCC.